# Help me to solve 3 Pass DiffiHellman protocol

Tags: diffie-hellman

I am trying to solve 3pass Diffihellman problem. However, I could not solve it. Is there any specific rule exist to select a1 and b1 or problem in the calculation. Please help me to solve this problem.
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as the "3 pass Diffie Hellman protocol". Without looking at it too closely, what you describe seems to be Shamir's three-pass protocol. Can you clarify?

Assuming this holds: One mistake of yours is that, when calculating $a_1^{-1} \mod{p-1}$, you pick $p - 1 = 8$ instead of $p - 1 = 16$.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comment. I have solved the problem. The solution is given below.
[image]

Comment: We rather prefer writing instead of photos of handwritten papers.

Comment: Indeed, pictures are not hosted by stackexchange and can become 404, while a copy of the text here will stay and it can be searched. This way, your question and answer have a better chance to help someone else.